# Upload file to drive with reactjs and nextjs

Tags: reactjs, pdf, next.js, google-drive-api, local

I am using this https://github.com/rpldy/drive-uploady to update files but this library only shows an example where you have to upload files from local. If i have a file (base64 url) or a blob (which i get from a pdf file i got from google drive before) how can i use this. I have tried multiple resource but no thing can give me result.

Here: https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady/tree/master/packages/ui/uploady

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

Drive-Uploady is mainly a sender for Uploady. Therefore, you are able to use most of Uploady's functionality. In this case, the [upload](https://react-uploady.netlify.app/docs/api/context/#upload) context method -

```js
import React from "react";
import DriveUploady, { useUploady } from "drive-uploady";


const MyButton = () => {
  const { upload } = useUploady();
  
  const onUpload = async () =>  {
  
    const myBlob = await getBlobFromSomewhere();
    
    upload(myBlob);
  };

  return <button onClick={onUpload}>Upload</button>
};

const App = () => {

  return <DriveUploady
          ...
          >
          <MyButton />
        </DriveUploady>
};
```

This will initiate the upload process once the button is clicked. Where you get the blob is your responsibility of course.